# How to reference a file stored on the Android internal storage in background-image in CSS

Tags: android, html, css, soti

An image file is stored on the internal storage on my Android tablet. I need to develop a HTML that shows the image on it.

The image is stored at `Internal Storage/Download/Agency/Kiosk/Logo-SAU.jgp`.

The DIV is defined in CSS as:

```
#logo_sau {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(file:///%sdcard%/Download/Agency/Kiosk/Logo-SAU.jpg);
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

This does not work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file:///sdcard/`, without the percent signs?